# How to install unity desktop over gnome?

Tags: gnome, unity

I installed Ubuntu gnome because I didn't want unity, but now I want the option to switch between unity and gnome. How do I get unity working?

Comment: if both are installed in log-in screen you can select whichever you like.

Answer (score 7):

Open the terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>) and run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-unity-desktop
```

Then log out, and before you log in, you should be able to change the desktop enviroment.

Answer (score 2):

Go to terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>) then type

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe it is as simple as installing the ubuntu-desktop package.

http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/ubuntu-desktop