# How to change between Unity and GNOME 3?

Tags: 16.04, unity, gnome, desktop-environments

[How to install unity desktop over gnome?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/493763/how-to-install-unity-desktop-over-gnome/493780) this thread showed me how to install Unity desktop on GNObuntu (ubuntu gnome, i just like to call it gnobuntu for some reason but whatever), how can i switch between desktop enviroments?

Comment: `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop` will add the Unity (default) desktop to your 16.04 system.  At login (assuming you don't have autologin) you'll see a gear logo, click it and you can select your DEsktop - gnome or unity

Comment: OP uses [Zorin OS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1005275/how-to-change-between-unity-and-gnome-3#comment1626842_1005278).

Comment: Zorin is NOT Ubuntu or an official flavor, hence this question is **off-topic** for this site. You should use Stack Exchange's Unix & Linux site https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both desktops are installed. You should be able to switch between them from the login screen when you first boot up the computer, by clicking on gear icon to select from installed desktops. Then just log out of account without powering down to switch between desktops. I think there may also be some hotkey like solution to this too but I don't remember it well enough.

Comment: Yea, but i don't see any options to change it. Even though I am using zorinOS (which is based on ubuntu), i can't find it.

Comment: oh you didn't mention in your question you were using zorinOS. Hopefully someone else can help you then. But it may be a picture like a gear or some such and not explicitly labeled. Also I think there are ways to install different login screens but I never did that.

Comment: I can see the gear icon, but only on the username select (sort of) thingy i don't know how to call it. When i select my username then type in my password (with no flaws) it says it's not working. Probably because i can't log into a listed user, but when i select my main user, i don't see the gear icon. Any solutions? (btw i disabled autologin)

Comment: This is sort of what I was talking about with the hotkey solution. something with using one of the function keys to switch between desktop environments. if you do a little more googling from the info in  this link I think you might be able to figure out a workaround.                                                                                
https://journalxtra.com/linux/desktop/multiple-desktops-on-one-linux-pc-now-thats-greedy/

Comment: Zorin is NOT Ubuntu or an official flavor, hence this question is **off-topic** for this site.  You should use Stack Exchange's Unix & Linux Q&A site  https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: oh well nevermind, I can click the cog but when i select "Ubuntu" (which is unity i guess) it just selects the GNOME 3 desktop.