# A completely different GUI for Ubuntu 14.04.6 LTS

Tags: 14.04, gui

I am a little scared with my OS. I had Ubuntu 14.04.6 LTS installed on my laptop and it looked like this:
[Old GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8OJL.png)

[image]

Today, I booted up the system and it looks like this:
[New GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPe1y.png)
[image]

Does anybody have any idea of what might have happened?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you upgrade your release?  Ubuntu 14.04 has been EOL for quite some time now.

Comment: Off hand would say it changed from Unity to gnome desktop.  This should only happen if you(someone) installed gnome desktop or you upgraded to 18.04.  14.04 is out of support now also and not really supported on this site.

Comment: @Terrance  that does not happen with the unity desktop, it is a very different look.

Comment: @Terrance  there is, top is unity, bottom is gnome.  They are similar but different.  Unity does have option to hide side panel, if people want it hidden or it can be seen all the time.

Comment: @crip659 Doesn't matter anyway.  14.04 is off topic.

Comment: @Terrance  Think we should leave it open for now till more information comes.  Looks like an upgrade to 18.04 was made, which would change the desktop, or something funny happened.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install unity desktop over gnome?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/493763/how-to-install-unity-desktop-over-gnome)