# Not changing UI

Tags: gui

In 21.04, the UI should be displayed like this (image from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_21.04_(Hirsute_Hippo))):

[image: Ubuntu 21.04 with Gnome desktop]

But, it displays like this in my computer:

[image: Ubuntu 21.04 with Unity desktop]

I upgraded 16.04 to 18.04, then 18.04 to 20.04, then 20.04 to 21.04.
How can I fix this UI?

Comment: What is wrong with the UI and who said wiki is correct?

Comment: I’m confuzzled. Is the concern the lack of desktop icons? You may be able to have them enabled by toggling some of the display settings 

Comment: I don't see the problem, please update your question and explain.

Comment: The problem is that you upgraded from 16.04 to 21.04 which is not a supported upgrade path.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install unity desktop over gnome?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/493763/how-to-install-unity-desktop-over-gnome)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In 16.04, *Unity* was the default Desktop environment. As you used an unsupported upgrade path from 16.04 -> 21.04 it was not changed after your upgrade. So, you're still using `unity-desktop` as default.

Install `ubuntu-desktop` if not already installed and switch the Desktop Environment to *Gnome* before you login.

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
```

You probably also need to change your Display manager to `gdm3` (Default in 16.04 was `lightdm`). Run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3` and chose `gdm3`.

---

However... I guess, you will notice more issues related to using an unsupported upgrade path. If that is the case, you should consider a reinstall.

Comment: I upgraded it by 16.04 to 18.04 to 20.04 to 21.04. It took about 1 days!

Comment: There is no tested, supported upgrade path directly from 20.04 to 21.04. That suggests you used an *unsupported* method. In turn, that suggests you may have used unsupported methods for other steps of your upgrades. We don't know what you did wrong -- there are too many possible variables. I can tell you that test installs that I have *properly* release-upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04 correctly switched from Unity to Gnome.

Comment: No I mean I upgraded 16.04 to 18.04 then 18.04 to 20.04 then 20.04 to 21.04. But I accidently removed GNOME a while ago and I will install 16.04 and upgrade to 18.04