# Installation of Ubuntu Unity

Tags: unity

I understand that Ubuntu Unity 21.10 is available.  I am using Ubuntu 20.04LTS with a Unity desktop display (which mostly works).  What do I need to do to install Ubuntu Unity 21.10?  Will such an installation trash the applications I have currently installed?

Comment: does [this article](https://ubuntuunity.org/post/ubuntu-unity-21.10/) answer your question?

Comment: Migrating from 20.04 to 21.10 requires a reinstall. A reinstall might (or might not) trash your data and applications -- it depends on your skill reading the installer prompts and whether your system is highly customized or not.

Comment: I would stay with 20.04, 22.04 will be out next spring and has five years of support.  21.10 only supported for nine months.  Might be mistaken but Ubuntu Unity 21.10 is a full OS install, not just an update for unity, so you would be installing over your OS.

Comment: Then, if I were to try to install Unity, I would need to download the ISO onto media and proceed from there, I take it.  I had hoped there would be a way to directly install from the web.  Guess I'm being to optomistic.

Comment: Please be aware; in https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, you'll note Ubuntu and official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.  Ubuntu Unity is a unofficial *re-spin* at this point in time (off-topic), hoping to become an official *flavor* (on-topic).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install unity desktop over gnome?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/493763/how-to-install-unity-desktop-over-gnome)

Comment: Ubuntu Unity is not an official flavor of Ubuntu.

Comment: I will provide details for *official* flavors of Ubuntu.  You can *upgrade via re-install* main Ubuntu, Xubuntu, Lubuntu, Kubuntu, Ubuntu-MATE, Ubuntu-Studio, Ubuntu-Budgie..  as a *clean* install where the system is new & nothing is saved; or as an *unclean* install where no user file is touched, your user configs are untouched & remain the same & *manually installed* packages get re-installed automatically post-install; ie. you control what is done. However you're asking about a Ubuntu *respin* and not *flavor* and I don't know what will happen there (and you're off-topic on this site!)